# Javascript snippet runner supporting ES 6 (like jsFiddle)

Tags: javascript, code-snippets, ecmascript-6

Apparently, neither jsFiddle, nor codepen.io support ES6 syntax (e.g. running `let x = 10` will throw an error - [see for yourself](http://jsfiddle.net/vbwu2mjy/)).

Obvious choice would be [es6fiddle](http://www.es6fiddle.net/), but it produces [clearly false results](http://www.es6fiddle.net/i29msptf/) (block-scoped variable i stays defined out of scope).

Is there any snippet runner at all, supporting ES6?

Comment: You could check out [Continuum](http://benvie.github.io/continuum/), though it's not really a jsFiddle. No DOM interaction.

Comment: You could include Traceur(https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler) and run your examples in jsFiddle and what not: """ Traceur is a JavaScript.next-to-JavaScript-of-today compiler that allows you to use features from the future today. Traceur's goal is to inform the design of new JavaScript features which are only valuable if they allow you to write better code. Traceur allows you to try out new and proposed language features today, helping you say what you mean in your code while informing the standards process."""

Comment: @NikolayMelnikov I guess that's what **es6fiddle** does. There are no block-scoped variables in ES5, so when you compile ES6 to ES5, I guess you can't emulate block scope in any way - so I'll end up with the same false results as in **es6fiddle**.
But thanks for the option anyway, maybe I'm wrong - will try it out :)

Comment: I was also playing with `es6fiddle` now and noticed that block-scopes didn't work there.

Comment: Block scope can be emulated. Not sure why they don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The particular problem you are seeing is due to [a bug in Traceur](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler/issues/1358), the ES6 to ES5 transpiler that many snippet runners use to add "ES6 support." You'll find that such runners are generally limited by the software running them, and in the case of Traceur, that means usually-excellent, but sometimes-buggy, ES6 support.

Answer (score 2):

You could try Babel. I don't know how it works under the hood, but Ember.js is using it as an ES6 polyfill, so it should be pretty reliable. They provide a web-based console for you to play around with. It shows you what your ES6 code ends up being transformed into: https://babeljs.io/repl/

Comment: "Polyfill" isn't quite the right word; babel transpiles es6 down to es5.

Answer (score 0):

You can set JavaScript transpilers with http://codepen.io now. One of them is babel which allows ES6. The process is transparent.

You have to go to settings then use the JavaScript tab.

Answer (score 0):

We can use jsFiddle itself to run ES6 snippet. Change the language from JavaScript to Babel. [image]